# What is the difference between sticky and fixed header?

Tags: wordpress, web

In WordPress theme, there are sticky and fixed headers. I am confused about their difference. In my opinion, sticky header is the one which sticks on the top while user scrolls page up/down. And the fixed header moves with the page scroll.

Some websites use the term Sticky and fixed alternatively that means both are same. Then what that header is called which moves with the page scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the fixed header is always on the same position during the page scroll.But the sticky header maybe scroll with the page at first, and from a certain point it goes to the fixed type. Just like the right subnavigation of bootstrap document. http://v3.bootcss.com/css/

Also bootstrap provide a js plugin to achieve the sticky effect http://v3.bootcss.com/javascript/#affix